# Python: recursion func for nested list

Tags: python, recursion

I need to unpack a nested list of this type:

```
lst = [5,2,3,[4,5, (6,7, [9])]]
```

to this:

```
[5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
```

What I did:

```
def unpack_seq(sequence: List[Any]) -> List[Any]:
    final_lst = []
    for el in sequence:
        if isinstance(el, list) or isinstance(el, tuple):
            res = final_lst.append(unpack_seq(el))
        else:
            res = final_lst.append(el)
    return res
result =  unpack_seq([1,2,3,[4,5, (6,7, [9])]])

print(result)
```

And I get --> NONE

What's wrong with my code?

Please, don't advise using Flatten, I am not supposed to use it and want to understand what I did wrong here.
I also used a function from [GeekforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-flatten-a-nested-list-using-recursion/), but it doesn't work as needed.

Thank you!

Comment: `append` modifies the list in place and returns `None`.

Comment: So you should be returning `final_lst`, not the result from append.

Comment: @user2736738  if I return 'final_lst' the result is this [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7, [9]]]], 
and without append just '9'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans no, it doesn't. The list there is easier, and I can't use the functions that are proposed there. But thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean "I can't use the functions that are proposed there"? Is this homework? Because that _radically_ changes the kind of answer you're looking for (real code and homework code are very much not the same thing ;) and should be mentioned in your post (asking about homework is fine, as long as you make it clear that you need an artificial answer, rather than a real world solution, which future visitors may not benefit from)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans exactly, this is homework :) 
oki, I'll be more precise next time

Comment: You have an [edit] button: please update _this_ post too, not just the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive None in output because the append() method returns nothing.
Following your logic, I propose this solution:

```
def unpack_seq(sequence: Iterable[Any]) -> List[Any]:
    final_lst = []
    for el in sequence:
        if isinstance(el, list) or isinstance(el, tuple):
            final_lst.extend(unpack_seq(el)) 
        else:
            final_lst.append(el)
    return final_lst
```

For the 'sequence' parameter I advise you to replace the 'List' type by 'Iterable' because it could cause problems if you pass a tuple to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Could be someone's homework, so I m not going to post everything.

```
res = final_lst.append(unpack_seq(el))
```

appends to final_lst, then returns **None** that gets stored to res...

I think you wanted to return the final_lst instead...

The problem is that you cannot just `final_lst.append(unpack_seq(el))`
because the result of unpack_seq(el) is a list, so you should add all its elements, not just append it... Checkout [extend](https://www.w3resource.com/python/list/list_extend.php)...

An alternative would have been to suppose its something that
can be iterated and catch the exception if its not...
[Edit:] As mentioned will only work with numbers though...

Comment: This implementation flattens things like strings too! Try `unpack(['foo', 'bar'])` to see what I mean.

Comment: right, because they can be iterated as if they were a list of letters... :) This will flatten anything that has a length :) But the question was about a list of numbers...